# can't create schema as admin

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I have a user `dbadmin`, which has the highest permissions possible in AWS RDS.

Using `dbadmin` I created a database, `foo`, owned by `fooadmin`.

As `fooadmin`, I can `CREATE SCHEMA` in that database. As `dbadmin`, I cannot, I get this error:

```
create schema ff;
ERROR:  permission denied for database foo
```

My `dbadmin` user certainly has access to this database:

```
grant create on database foo to dbadmin;
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "foo"
GRANT
```

This is sort of the inverse of [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/176155/unable-to-create-schema-on-amazon-rds-for-postgres), which was asking how to elevate privileges for `fooadmin`.

**update 1** for EvanC:

```
select user;
 current_user
--------------
 dbadmin
(1 row)

sdm=> create schema ff;
ERROR:  permission denied for database foo
```

**update 2** workaround:

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45078346/change-privileges-on-schema-created-by-rdsadmin-user), if I change the database owner to the `dbadmin` account, I can at least create schemas as that user. Obviously it means `fooadmin` can't create schemas anymore. I suppose I could change the owner, create schemas, then change the owner back.

Comment: In my hands, 'WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "foo"' doesn't mean that dbadmin already had those privileges, but rather it means that whoever ran the command doesn't have the privilege to grant the privilege.

Comment: @EvanCarroll added that.